# Laravel 5.6 : mostrar campo de una tabla relacionada con otra por otro campo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy creando una pequeña aplicación CRM.

Me da el siguiente error cuando intento mostrar el nombre del cliente en la vista de editar reunión

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /resources/views/empleado/reunion/edit.blade.php)
>
> ```
>  <option value="<?php echo e($reunion->cliente_id); ?>" selected hidden><?php echo e($reunion->cliente->nombre); ?></option>
> ```

Tengo los siguientes modelos, controladores y vistas de Clientes y Reuniones:

**Cliente.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use App\Filters\ClienteFilter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'email','direccion', 'telefono', 'nif', 'esEmpresa', 'comercial_id', 'riesgo', 'notas'];
    //Un cliente puede tener asociadads muchas reuniones
    public function reunion(){
        return $this->hasMany(Reunion::class);
    }  
    //Constructor de filtros para el usuario
    public function scopeFilter(Builder $builder, $request)
    {
        return (new ClienteFilter($request))->filter($builder);
    }
    public function archivar()
    {
        return $reunion->archivado = 1;
    }
}
```

**Reunion.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use App\Filters\ReunionFilter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Reunion extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reuniones';
    protected $fillable = ['usuario_id', 'cliente_id', 'titulo', 'descripcion', 'estado','archivado'];
    //Una reunión sólo puede pertenecer a un cliente
    public function cliente(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class);
    }
    //Una reunión puede tener muchos comentarios
    public function comment(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
    //Constructor de filtros para la reunion
    public function scopeFilter(Builder $builder, $request)
    {
        return (new ReunionFilter($request))->filter($builder);
    }
    //Función que de momento no se usa, era para cambiar el valor del campo "archivado" en la tabla reunion
    public function archivar()
    {
        return $reunion->archivado = 1;
    }

    public function nombreCliente(){
        return $cliente->nombre;
    }
}
```

**ReunionController.php**

```
/**
     * Muestra el formulario de edición del producto.
     * @param type $id
     * @return type
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $reunion = Reunion::find($id);
        $archivado = Reunion::select('archivado');
        $clientes = Cliente::select('id','nombre')->where('comercial_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return view($this->view_path.'.edit', compact('reunion','clientes', 'archivado','id'));
    }
```

Vista editar reunión, pongo el trozo de código dónde da el fallo.

**edit.blade.php**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 tarjeta">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body" style="padding:30px">
      <form method="post" action="{{action('Empleado\ReunionController@update', $id)}}">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="titulo">Modificar asunto:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" value="{{$reunion->titulo}}">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion">Modificar detalles:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="descripcion" id="notas">{{$reunion->descripcion}}</textarea>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
               <label for="cliente_id">Modificar cliente: </label>
               <select name="cliente_id">
                   <option value="{{$reunion->cliente_id}}" selected hidden>{{$reunion->cliente->nombre}}</option>
                @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
                   <option value="{{$cliente['id']}}">{{$cliente['nombre']}}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
               <label for="archivado">Archivado: </label>
               <select name="archivado">
                   <option value="0" @if ($reunion->archivado == '0') selected="selected" @endif>No</option>
                   <option value="1" @if ($reunion->archivado == '1') selected="selected" @endif>Sí</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label >Modificar fecha</label>
              <input type="date" name="date" min="01-01-2018"
                     max="31-12-2100" value="{{$reunion->date}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label >Modificar hora</label>
              <input type="time" name="time" min="8:00"
                     max="22:00" value="{{$reunion->time}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="estado">Modificar estado:</label>
              <select name="estado">
                <option value="Obra sin empezar" @if ($reunion['estado'] == 'Obra sin empezar') selected="selected" @endif >Obra sin empezar</option>
                <option value="Obra en ejecución" @if ($reunion['estado'] == 'Obra en ejecución') selected="selected" @endif>Obra en ejecución</option>
                <option value="Obra casi terminada" @if ($reunion['estado'] == 'Obra casi terminada') selected="selected" @endif>Obra casi terminada</option>
                <option value="Obra terminada" @if ($reunion['estado'] == 'Obra terminada') selected="selected" @endif>Obra terminada</option> 
              </select>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Actualizar reunión</button>
            <br>
            <a href="/empleado/reuniones" class="btn" role="button">Volver a reuniones</a>
          </div>
      </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

EDITO: Código que muestra haciendo dd($reunion) como comenta el compañero Pedro:

```
Reunion {#281 ▼
  #table: "reuniones"
  #fillable: array:6 [▼
    0 => "usuario_id"
    1 => "cliente_id"
    2 => "titulo"
    3 => "descripcion"
    4 => "estado"
    5 => "archivado"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:12 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "usuario_id" => 5
    "usuario_nombre" => "Ernesto"
    "cliente_id" => 1
    "titulo" => "OE6wpc5GMO8w77v"
    "descripcion" => "r22y5btkPpJXpso4Ixm6IxfDYFGcKcaPoJSIO23gLmH5xL7ZoOd1YUQQQu7L67hFJMiKhUWOACnAYkhK"
    "estado" => "Obra sin empezar"
    "archivado" => 1
    "date" => "2018-07-30"
    "time" => "11:14:00"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => "2018-07-27 09:34:31"
  ]
  #original: array:12 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "usuario_id" => 5
    "usuario_nombre" => "Ernesto"
    "cliente_id" => 1
    "titulo" => "OE6wpc5GMO8w77v"
    "descripcion" => "r22y5btkPpJXpso4Ixm6IxfDYFGcKcaPoJSIO23gLmH5xL7ZoOd1YUQQQu7L67hFJMiKhUWOACnAYkhK"
    "estado" => "Obra sin empezar"
    "archivado" => 1
    "date" => "2018-07-30"
    "time" => "11:14:00"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => "2018-07-27 09:34:31"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese error significa que `$reunion` no es un objeto. Esto se puede dar porque sea nulo, es decir, que no se haya encontrado ninguna reunión con el id que pasas a la función.

Comment: Eso está porque la primera opción del select es el cliente que ya fué asociado cuando se creó la reunión. Así que una vez se edite la reunión, si no se edita el cliente se sigue seleccionando el mismo que estaba asociado.

Comment: Modifico la respuesta. Una de dos, o la reunión no se creó o no se encontró. El problema está ahí.

Comment: Pero he puesto ese trozo de código porque es dónde da el error pero creo que no va relacionado con que no encuentre la reunión con el id que se le pasa a la función ya que si quito ese código pero dejo el resto que también hace referencia a $reunion , no da ningún problema.

Comment: Pon el código entero de edit.blade.php porque hay más $reunion

Comment: Edito con el código completo de edit.blade.php

Comment: En ReunionController, justo después de $reunion = Reunion::find($id); haz dd($reunion); a ver que sale.

Comment: Editado con el resultado de añadir dd($reunion).

Comment: Solo me queda como opción que $reunion->cliente no sea un objeto (o esté vacío) y por lo tanto el error venga provocado por $reunion->cliente->nombre. Haz un dd con $reunion->cliente->nombre o con $reunion->cliente a ver el resultado.